# Android: Change the z-order of the view

Tags: java, android

I have many views in my xml, and now I wanna ***change one view's z order*** in code in order to bring it to other views' front but **not all** the other views' front.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is `.bringToFront()` but you would have to do it for more than one view in your case.

Comment: yeah, this is the answer i want.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This can help

```
layout.bringChildToFront(view);
```

here

```
layout = your_linear_layout AND 
view = the_view_you_wanna_bring_to_front
```

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove it from it's parent and re-add it it will be in front.  Of every other child in that parent.  If this fits how you want it to be in front of some things and not others then this should help.